# Rails 2.3.2 and MySQL 5.5.x

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to switch my 2.3.2 rails app from MySQL server 5.1.39 to newer MySQL 5.5.x version. Is there any possible risks? Is 2.3.2 Rails version compatible with MySQL server 5.5.x?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the abstraction between Rails and MySQL is clean enough that going from one 5.? version of MySQL to another 5.? version shouldn't cause you any trouble.

The only way to really find out is to upgrade your dev environment to MySQL 5.5 and run your tests.

Would also recommend you take the time to get up to the latest/greatest Rails 2.3 brach, which is 2.3.11.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that, no worries just update.

Using three different versions for the same application on different boxes without any issues. I would still suggest taking backup of your database before going for such update.

regards